# Why does test fails while browsers doesn't testing AngularJS apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, google-chrome, phantomjs

The last days I've been trying to test AngularJS 1.3.15 code. Today it is driving me nuts giving me errors that I can't reproduce on normal GUI browsers.

First issue is with the `current` property of [$route](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route). The controller is as following:

```
...
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$route', function($route) {
    var user = $route.current.locals.user;
...
```

The above will throw error while testing but it will note give any error on the browser.

**Tests Output**

In Chrome it fails!

```
Chrome 41.0.2272 (Linux) Controller: HomeCtrl $controller.user should have an user FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'locals' of undefined
        at new <anonymous> (/home/lucio/chatbeats/app/app.js:26:28)
```

In PhantomJS it fails!

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) Controller: HomeCtrl $controller.user should have an user FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'locals' of undefined
        at new <anonymous> (/home/lucio/chatbeats/app/app.js:26:28)
```

**Browsers output**

In Chrome it works!

[image: renders page correctly]

In Firefox it works!

[image: renders page correctly]

In Chromium it works!

[image: renders page correctly]

Second issue is with `$scope`. To check that the previous problem is not caused by a bad handled asynchronous call (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369780/1505348)), I've tried to set a listener with `$scope.$on`:

```
...
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
      console.log($route.current);
    });
...
```

The test suite will not recognize `$scopeProvider` whilst the browser will.

**Tests Output**

In Chrome it fails!

```
Chrome 41.0.2272 (Linux) Controller: HomeCtrl $controller.user should not have the user signed in FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- HomeCtrl
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20HomeCtrl
```

In PhantomJS it fails!

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) Controller: HomeCtrl should do something FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- HomeCtrl
```

**Browsers output**

In Chrome it works!

[image: prints the object to console]

In Firefox it works!

[image: prints the object to console]

In Chromium it works!

[image: prints the object to console]

**NOTE:** I ran both applications under the same grunt task which means both were running *almost* at the same time.

Tools in use:

- Jasmine v2.2.0
- Karma v0.12.32
- PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) (for unit testing from CLI)
- Chrome 41.0.2272 (for unit testing from CLI)
- Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit) (for manual testing from GUI)
- Chromium Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) (for manual testing from GUI)
- Firefox version 37.0.2 (for manual testing from GUI)

You can check out the whole project from [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ABaZTnWcGza45YaKX8CQ?p=preview%20Plunker).

Please, correct me if I'm missing something on the code.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to avoid manual testing for AngularJS applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*$route*

Unit tests are typically independent of routing, so the documentation and most examples you see don't include angular-route.js in the test runner. This means that the $route service won't exist in the app under test (hence being undefined). So when you instantiate a controller that takes $route as a dependency, you need to provide a mock object as the dependency in order to simulate the current routing state.

```
$controller('HomeCtrl', {
    $route: {
        current: {
            locals: {
                user: { name: 'someUser' }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

*$scope*

When angular instantiates a controller for you during normal app running in the browser, the scope that the controller gets associated with is automatically decided for you. In tests, since you're creating the controller yourself, you also need to create and assign the scope to the controller yourself. You might have come across the following  in the documentation. This just creates a new scope as a child of the $rootScope, and passes that as the dependency for the controller. You use a new scope rather than the $rootScope directly so that your tests don't pollute the $rootScope (aka the global scope).

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();

$controller('HomeCtrl', {
    $scope: scope
});
```

Combining the two:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();

$controller('HomeCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    $route: {
        current: {
            locals: {
                user: { name: 'someUser' }
            }
        }
    }
});
```